# wireshark how to narrow analysis to a given timeframe

Tags: wireshark

This might be a very trivial thing to do but I am very new to wireshark.

I have a capture stream from tcpdump. How do I restrict my analysis to a smaller time window?

(I have presently hacked it using `frame.number` in filters but that is a very brittle filter.)

Comment: Finally figured it out: In frame.time I have to use date time in local TZ, and not UTC which is what is what I was using for display.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use e.g.

```
.5 < frame.time_relative < .75
```

where the times are specified as seconds from the start of capture (the same as displayed in the "Time" column).

As a hint, you can right-click on any column or detail entry and use "Prepare a Filter -> Selected" to see what field it would filter on. This can be used to quickly learn what filter expression to write.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is quite a nice tool.